# How to encrypt message in WCF by writing code

Tags: c#, wcf, security

I want to develop a wcf service which will send encrypted message / response to client and client will decrypt it and same way client will send data in encrypted format which wcf service decrypt it before taking any action.

I heard that wcf has message inspector which can do it but not getting any easy understanding sample code to achieve the same. so please give me a sample code how to achieve it. Also give me sample code for both wcf service and client side code.

Please do not tell me to use certificate rather guide me what kind of code I need to write at service end and client to encrypt/decrypt data. Please discuss here or redirect me to relevant article. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need certificate at least for encrypting username and password.

> Sending unencrypted username and password over any communication
>   framework is not the best scenario. Therefore when we choose the
>   UserName client credential type WCF insists that your service must
>   also reference a service certificate that contains a private key. The
>   public key in this certificate is used to protect the confidentiality
>   of the username and password sent to the service. The private key is
>   then used by the service to obtain those encrypted credentials.

Here is the step by step tutorial:

[Securing a WCF service with Username and Password using Message security and the Channel Factory pattern](http://www.felinesoft.com/blog/index.php/2014/02/securing-a-wcf-service-with-username-and-password-using-message-security-and-the-channel-factory-pattern/)

Comment: i already said that i am not position to use certificate rather i want to @Vano encrypt and decrypt data by writing code. i heard that it can be done my message inspector but found none good write for message inspector which encrypt and decrypt data fro service end and client end. so looking for good guidance and write up to implement. thanks